# Mudei de mysqli para PDO e não consigo obter o row

Tags: php, pdo

**No meu mysqli era fácil**

```
$_SESSION['userphoto'] = $row['userphoto'];
```

Como fazer funcionar no PDO ?

**ConexãoLogin.php**

```
session_start();

$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->bindParam(':senha', md5($_POST['senha']));
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($row > 0){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['userphoto'] = $row['userphoto'];

    //$_SESSION funcionava certo no MYSQLI
```

Comment: Acho que você está confuso amigo :)

Comment: Você sobreacreveu $row e perdeu a informação que te interessava

Comment: Já removi essa variável

Comment: Como vc espera apenas uma linha do banco de dados tenta substitui `fetchAll` por apenas `fetch`.

Comment: exatamente o que o @rray respondeu

Comment: Irei tentar isto amanhã

Comment: Nota: Para quem estranhou o meu primeiro comentário, na verdade ele se refere a primeira versão da pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/58469/1 :) Boa noite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) retorna um array com todos os registros da consulta, ele é nesse formato:

```
array(0 => array('email' => 'email1', 'senha' => 'senha1'),
      1 => array('email' => 'email2', 'senha' => 'senha2));
```

Nesse caso para retornar apenas um registro use [fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) ou use o indice zero do seu array.

**Opção 1 - Recomendada**

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(count($row) > 0){
   $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
   $_SESSION['userphoto'] = $row['userphoto'];
```

**Opção 2**

```
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(count($row) > 0){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['userphoto'] = $row[0]['userphoto']; //usando indice zero
```

Comment: obrigado pela boa resposta , alterei também minha conexão sql que com ela não estava dando certo :s / $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Nome, senha FROM login WHERE Email=:email AND senha=:senha"); para SELECT *